Typescript create an enum by combining keys of two other enums with concatenation
I have two enums. I am not sure how to take each of the first and loop through the second to create a new enum of each combination. These are the two enums:
enum AppEntity{
CUSTOMER = 'customer',
SUPPLIER = 'supplier',
DOCUMENT = 'document'
}

enum AppAction{
VIEW = 'view',
CREATE = 'create',
EDIT = 'edit',
DELETE = 'delete'
}

How can I dynamically create a type that gives me:
enum Permissions{
 VIEW_CUSTOMER = 'view customer',
CREATE_CUSTOMER = 'create customer'
...
}

and so on?
The purpose of this is to not have to list out each of the permissions in an enum so that I can simply use it for checking types during development.
Thanks to ChatGPT I found the answer:
export type AppPermissions = {
    [K in `${PermissionAction} ${PermissionModel}`]: K extends `${infer A}_${infer E}`
        ? A extends keyof AppAction
            ? E extends keyof AppEntity
                ? `${Extract<AppAction, A>} ${Extract<AppEntity, E>}`
                : never
            : never
        : never;
};

This allows me to create a type I can use to ensure a string is a key of the resulting type.
